# 2 Piece... Color this #div... Image gallery opinions

Tags: css, image-gallery

I am currently using Wordpress for my new website mangapunch.com. I cannot seem to properly set the color for the top area of the menu. Any ideas?

```
/* Sidebar Background Color */
@media all and (min-width:601px) 
{div#sidebar {color: #5E5A5A !important;background: #5E5A5A;}
/* --Sidebar Background Color */    
@media all and (max-width:600px) 
{.search-field, #sidebar, div#sidebar_close {color: #5E5A5A !important;background:#5E5A5A;}
```

Is what I currently have.

Oh and bonus points for anyone who can figure out how to implement gallery in this style http://www.mangapanda.com/naruto/688. Or any suggestions for something better to display manga.